# Modern CMake: Superbuild with library that defines multiple export sets

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management

It seems to be common practice (at least its possible) to define multiple export sets for a library, e.g. one with and one without namespace. The example, I stumbled upon can be found in the [CMakeLists.txt of the library GeographicLib](https://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/code/ci/release/tree/cmake/CMakeLists.txt):

```
install (EXPORT targets
  FILE ${PROJECT_NAME_LOWER}-targets.cmake
  DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")
install (EXPORT targets
  NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
  FILE ${PROJECT_NAME_LOWER}-namespace-targets.cmake
  DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}")
```

I can see the benefits, however, when including this library in a superbuild (i.e. using [FetchContent_MakeAvailable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) as suggested in various tutorials on "Modern CMake"), this raises an issue when trying to `INSTALL(EXPORT...)` the top-level project as it tries to also export the dependency, which is included in multiple export sets (error below again with GeographicLib as example):

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT <TOP_LEVEL_EXPORT_TARGETS> ...) includes target "<TOP_LEVEL_TARGET>" which requires target "GeographicLib" that is not in this export set, but in multiple other export sets: cmake/geographiclib-targets.cmake, cmake/geographiclib-namespace-targets.cmake.
An exported target cannot depend upon another target which is exported multiple times. Consider consolidating the exports of the "GeographicLib" target to a single export.
```

I am trying to find a work-around without having to modify the CMakeLists.txt of the library. Any suggestions? Am I missing something obvious here... ?

Comment: As far as I understand, CMake problem is following: When generate an export file for `TOP_LEVEL_EXPORT_TARGETS`, CMake needs to add linkage with `GeographicLib` target. But this linkage should be not with the original target, but with its **exported** variant. CMake may detect name of the exported target according to the export set. But with two export sets CMake cannot decide which target name to use, `GeographicLib` or `GeographicLib::GeographicLib`. I see the only way to overcome this problem: modify the GeographicLib project and remove the extra export sets. E.g. with `PATCH_COMMAND`.

Comment: I follow your understanding of the problem. Thank you for pointing me towards the `PATCH_COMMAND` argument which I didn't know about. I successfully implemented a work-around using it (hint for Windows users: don't use quotes in the argument value). It would still be great to find a non-intrusive way to solve this. I am trying hard to follow "modern CMake" standards and workflows and it's frustrating to see how easy these workflows break in practice...